# Read Firebase token in Fragment or Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase using [this code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java) and I'm able to see the refresh token in logcat.

I am trying to store the token so that I can use it in a Fragment

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().putString("regToken", token).commit();  
}
```

When I try to read it in my Fragment, where I will send the token to a server, I'm unable to read it:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("regToken", "false");
```

Unfortunately, it fails to read `regToken` and returns `false` once the Fragment is invoked.

How can I read the stored value from MyFirebaseInstanceIDService in my Fragment? I suspect the issue is with "different context's". If so, how can I use "the same" context when storing/reading.

Comment: Token is not refreshed on each app launch. It is possible that you installed the app first without this code snippet and then added it. If you then ran the app it will not refresh the token and this method won't be called if it's in onTokenRefreshed() method.

Comment: I make sure to uninstall the app before testing.
I am also able to see the token in logcat

Comment: I doubt that the context used is the problem.  You can get a common `Context` by using `getApplicationContext()` in the service and `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FirebaseInstanceId class provides a singleton that you can use anywhere to retrieve the current token.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Calling that in your Fragment where you are doing the sending to your server should work.

Comment: I did try that, but Android studio could not resolve. I might have missed something. With the delay however it now works. Thank you

Comment: Oh it would seem i did not try that at all. That works very well, and is probably a better solution than mine.
Thank you

Comment: Note that sometimes getToken() will return null if the token has not been generated yet, however if you implement the onTokenRefresh method in your FirebaseInstanceIdService extension you will be notified when the token is available and in that case getToken() will always return a valid token.

Comment: `getToken()` is deprecated. Use this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/d886d348a681f41f02e78d720cb74fb8c162e339/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MainActivity.java#L101-L118

Answer (score 0):

Create an Application Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public String Token;
}
```

Use this code to store the token

```
((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).Token = "Your Token";
```

and this piece of code to retrieve it back

```
String token  =  ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).Token
```

don't forget to add the Application class in AndroidManifist file like

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

and also you can change the `Token` Property of the MyAppliction class to private and use getters and setters to access this.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was some delay to get the refresh token, and therefore when i was trying to read the sharedpreferences, it was not yet written to.

By creating a small delay, I can now successfully read the token:

```
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String savedToken = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getString("pushToken", "false");
                    Log.e("SAVED", savedToken);
                }
            },
            3000);
```